# How to remove string's quotation marks which inside of a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a code block as shown below:

```
lst=[67310,0,"May the force be with you"]
print(" ".join(repr(i) for i in lst).replace("'",""))
```

Output is:

```
67310 0 May the force be with you
```

But if I had a list, something like that:

```
lst=[[67310,0,"May the force be with you"],[65310,1,"I'm getting too old for this stuff"]]
for j in lst:
    print(" ".join(repr(i) for i in j).replace("'",""))
```

The output is:

```
67310 0 May the force be with you
65310 1 "Im getting too old for this stuff"
```

The problem is I want a output without quotation marks like that:

```
67310 0 May the force be with you
65310 1 I'm getting too old for this stuff
```

How can I solve this problem easily? Thanks for help

Comment: If you replace `repr` with `str`, you should get what you're asking.

Comment: But also the apostrophe  which one is between I and m disappears. The output become like that: Im getting too old for this stuff

Comment: Replacing `"'"` with `""` replaces single quotes with nothing (an empty string).

Comment: Just use `str` in place of `repr`,  check in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try this, l think this is what you want.

```
lst=[[67310,0,"May the force be with you"],[65310,1,"I'm getting too old for this stuff"]]
for  j in lst:
    print(" ".join(str(i) for i in j).replace("'",""))

# 67310 0 May the force be with you
# 65310 1 Im getting too old for this stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
for j in lst:
    print(" ".join(repr(i) for i in j).replace('"', ''))
```

In your `.replace` you were replacing the`'`, not the `"`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But when I tried your answer  'May the force be with you' this happens

Comment: I wanted to just add it as a comment but don't have the rep yet heh., but as the other guy already mentioned, str() can also help.